# very sparse (and large) matrices and vectors for gradient descent in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, sparse-matrix

We are trying to find a solution to implement a stochastic gradient descent (or a coordinate gradient descent) on a very very very large and very sparse least-squares problem . That is to say, for the standard least squares problem:

min ||y - Ax||2

The matrix A on the order of a billion rows and a billion columns, but it is 99% sparse . Similarly, the coefficient vector x is about 98% sparse, and the observation vector Y is also about 97% sparse.

However, although I know that tensorflow has a stochastic gradient descent function, it's unclear to me whether the gradient descent functions accept sparse matrices/vectors, and even if they do, it's unclear if these gradient descent libraries behind the scenes eventually converts the sparse matrices and vectors into dense representations which would then defeat the point of having inputted the data in sparse format to begin with. If tensorflow's gradient descent method converts everything to dense format, we would blow up the memory easily and also blow up the performance (since we would have ~ 100 * 100 more computations needed for all those zero values.)

If the SGD algorithms implicitly convert sparse matrixes and vectors to their dense counterparts, how hard would it be to change that logic to a sparse only logic? As in, could a reasonably knowledgeable python/C++ engineer (with some tensorflow knowledge) do it or is a major architectural rewrite?